# Rails 3.2 Validation - Multiple Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an award model.  The NOMINATOR selects himself from a dropdown list, then selects the NOMINEE from another dropdown list.

How can I disallow self-nomination via a validation in the model?  In other words, the nominator cannot select himself from the nominee selection list.

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :nominator, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'nominator_id'
  belongs_to :nominee, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'nominee_id'
  validates :nominator_id, :nominee_id, :award_description, :presence => true
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base  

  belongs_to :nominator, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'nominator_id'
  belongs_to :nominee, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'nominee_id'

  validates :nominator_id, :nominee_id, :award_description, :presence => true
  validate :cant_nominate_self  

  def cant_nominate_self
    if nominator_id == nominee_id
      errors.add(:nominator_id, "can't nominate your self")
    end
  end
end
```

This is a custom validation.  More information about validations, including other ways to do custom validations, is available in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest - a custom validate method. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations for the details.

Comment: You're welcome.  And thanks @MrTheWalrus for the comment about Rails Guides; I added a link.